# event.clientX position issue in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer

I am learning javascript sample from [this page](https://web.archive.org/web/20101123222544/http://nofunc.org/AJAX_Star_Rating/),

I am confused about the following code snippets in function XY(e, v), especially the two statements

```
event.clientX + document.documentElement.scrollLeft
```

and

```
 event.clientY + document.documentElement.scrollTop
```

Could anyone let me know what is `document.documentElement.scrollLeft` and `document.documentElement.scrollTop`? And why we add it to `event.clientX` and `event.clientY` please (i.e. what meaningful values we could get when adding them to `event.clientX` and `event.clientY`)?

This is for Internet Explorer

Comment: What is your issue? The question is more about "what are those things?" for that you should search either via Google or at MDC: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`clientX` - Gets or sets the x-coordinate of the mouse pointer's position relative to the client area of the window, excluding window decorations and scroll bars.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms533567(VS.85).aspx

`scrollLeft` - Sets or retrieves the distance between the left edge of the object and the leftmost portion of the content currently visible in the window.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms534617(VS.85).aspx

In layman's, it is getting the mouse position on the screen (clientX and clientY) then adding that value to the current scroll position (scrollLeft and scrollTop) of the page to get the total pixel position for the point.

I.E. If you've viewing a page that has scrolled 200px down and the mouse click occurs at 200px down the client's viewing area, that would be at 400px down the document.

**EDIT:**

"Client area of the window" refers to the display area of Internet Explorer that you see/manipulate the page. It starts at 0px 0px in the upper left corner and is as wide/tall as your browser window is open (minus scroll bars, frame, title bar, etc).

In the example it is trying to get the absolute position of the event on the page by accounting for where in the "viewable area" of the browser you made the click and adding that to how far down/right the "viewable area" has scrolled on the page.

Comment: Thanks, I am confused about what means "client area of the window". I want to confirm with you that my understanding is correct. In the sample I posted in my original question, I think mouse move event of the object star whose id is "star" will treat the small star image area as the "client area of the window", is that understanding correct?

Comment: Nope, check the edit.  The example is getting the absolute position on the page of the star and comparing it to the absolute position on the page of the event.

Answer (score 1):

I got the same problem using this script on my site http://www.alterboutique.com

I found the solution here:
[experts-exchange](http://www.experts-exchange.com/Programming/Languages/Scripting/JavaScript/Q_23310105.html)

In the bottom of the page, there is a post from Kravimir, he gives the solution replacing the code of the function XY, by his code:

```
function XY(e,v) {
  e=e||window.event;
  var d=document,dE=d.documentElement,o;
  if(typeof(e.pageX)=='number')
    o={'X':e.pageX,'Y':e.pageY};
  else 
    o={'X':e.clientX+d.body.scrollLeft+(dE?dE.scrollLeft:0),
      'Y':e.clientY+d.body.scrollTop+(dE?dE.scrollTop:0)};
  return(v?o[v]:o);
}
```